# Why are saved model so large in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

I have implemented a neural network with an LSTM model (see below). After training the model with a hidden size of 512, I saved it by calling `torch.save(model).`

I expected the model size to measure in the low tens of kilobytes, accounting for three layers of LSTM's hidden parameters. I also enumerated the parameters via `model.named_parameters()`. I was surprised to find that the actual unzipped size of the parameters is more like 30 MB.

Why is the saved model so large?

```
class IRNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, obs_size, hidden_size):
        super(IRNN, self).__init__()

        self.num_layers = 3
        input_size = obs_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.hidden = self.init_hidden()
        self.hiddenc = self.init_hidden()
        self.rnn = nn.LSTM(
            input_size=input_size, hidden_size=hidden_size, num_layers=self.num_layers
        )
        self.i2o = nn.Linear(hidden_size, 256)
```

Comment: try doing `torch.save(model.state_dict(), PATH)` instead